# UIGestureRecognizers for single and double tap set in the xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xib, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have set two UITapGestureRecognizers in my xib on a UIImageView. I have also set their IBAction in the associated header file.
For the single tap gesture recognizer, I set taps and touches to 1, state to Enabled, and delayed touches ended to YES in the Attributes inspector.
For the double tap gesture recognizer, I set taps and touches to 2, state to Enabled, cancel touches in view to YES and delay touches ended to YES.

When I double tap on the UIImageView, it only triggers the IBAction method for the single tap. So, I decided to print the imageview.gestureRecognizer and it shows the UITapGestureRecognizer for single tap's state as Ended and the UITapGestureRecognizer for double tap's state as Possible.

I have been stuck on this for a couple hours. I found ways to do it programatically but I was wondering how I can do it by setting it in the xib itself.

Any help would be great! Thank you in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very good question. If you add gestures to code like this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(singleTap)];

singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doubleTap)] ;
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

And all works fine because you canceled first gesture here

```
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

If you add two gestures in xib you always should cancel single tap if there was a double tap. And you always need to use 2 properties for gestures and use

```
[self.firstGestureProperty requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.secondGestureOroperty];
```

For single tap:

[image]

For double tap:

[image]

Source code:

[image]

And everything works fine.